# Программа не видит *.url файл

Tags: java, url

у меня есть программа которая должна выполняться по нажатию кнопки, которая в свою очередь должна открыть ярлык со ссылкой, с помощью операции
`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Путь до ярлыка"));` .
И мне нужно собрать эту программу в jar архив, но проблема в том, что если я указываю НЕ абсолютную ссылку, например
`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("src/files/Clicker.url"));`
то после архивации в jar архив, программа отказывается видеть файл "Clicker.url", хотя если я запущу проект через IDea то все работает исправно, программа видит файл и запускает его. Так вот вопрос, как мне поместить этот файл "Clicker.url" в архив, чтобы программа видела его и запускала

Comment: потому что так делать нельзя. если вы хотите затолкать что-то в jar, то добавьте это в папку с ресурсами, а вот как выполнить чтение из ресурсов - тут гугл в помощь

Comment: не могли бы подсказать что за папка с ресурсами? Данный файл лежит в одной директории с *.java

Comment: папка находится в директории вашего проекта по пути src/main/resources

Comment: у меня нет такой папки, ни main ни resources, только файлы *.java в папке src

Comment: как вы создавали проект? вы вообще средой разработки пользуетесь?

Comment: пользуюсь Intellij Idea. Создал так File - New - Project и там Next - Next

Comment: а как вы эту папку пытались найти? тоже в идею смотрите? идея может по разному отображать структуру проектов. это можно выбирать по необходимости. но по сути можете просто найти папку с проектом на вашем жестком диске и добавить нужный файл в указанную папку

Comment: нет, я находил папку с проектом на жд и там смотрел, не было папки main. А нужным мне файл и так лежит в папке src и идея видит его и запускает, но когда я собираю в jar архив все , то этот файл отказывается запускаться.

Comment: я не понимаю, в чем ваш вопрос? я уже ответил в каком месте нужно сохранить файлы. нет каталога - создавайте. не знаете, что такое папка ресурсов и как с нее читать - ответов огромное количество даже в пределах этого форума